# Embedding web app in Google Sites doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have Google Apps Script deployed as "web app" linked to a spreadsheet google.
It displays a form and once you submit the form, it will process the data and put it in the spreadsheet, here the code :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EBo5DooJQtcFX5GORmtOB1ri2kkMPXX6nEMvNRsobOg/edit?usp=sharing

When I access the script directly via the link below there's no problem, it's working fine :
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyMu10ibB8dBLZj6hS_gfNSiaW4XxEnFuzVOvNHdQKcoX092Ayy/exec

But when I want to embedded like "web app" in google site like this, it doesn't work :
[image]

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

EDIT :
It's odd but when I tried to make a mock website (with the new version of Google site) to show you the problem, it's working :
https://sites.google.com/ggbearings.com/test/home

But it's not working on classic Google site, I guess I have to contact them to seek out an answer.

Comment: Press the f12 key in Chrome, and look in the console log.  Look for an error message.  Unless you have an error message and specific code, then this really isn't an "on topic" StackOverflow question.

Comment: Well the code is ok, no error in the console but where should I go then ? Because when I'm looking for support on Google they're redirecting me here...

Comment: @Danny: Create a [mcve] and add the code here.

Comment: You can ask the question in the [Apps Script Community - Link](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)  Unfortunately, the advice that Google provides for getting support is misleading, or at least incomplete, and they refuse to do anything about it.  From the advice that Google gives, It's easy to believe that StackOverflow is the place to go for general support.  But, the rules for StackOverflow don't allow for general usage questions, and basic support questions.  It happens all the time, and neither StackOverflow or Google seem to have any intention of stopping it.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed the autorisations, everyone can access the code now in the first link via Tools < Script Editor
Thank you for your response @SandyGood, I'll be checking